# Upgrade jQuery version from 1.7.1 to 1.11.2

Tags: jquery, upgrade

With my current application, I am using jQuery version 1.7.1. Now, I am planning to upgrade the jQuery version to 1.11.2.

Is there any patch available to provide the backward comparability to the existing application.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't recall there being many breaking changes from 1.7 > 1.11. Do you have a specific issue here?

Comment: there is the [migration plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/)... read the upgrade guid for each of the major versions([1.8](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/), [1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/), [1.10](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/24/jquery-1-10-0-and-2-0-1-released/), [1.11](http://blog.jquery.com/2014/01/24/jquery-1-11-and-2-1-released/)) to see what are the changes

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in 1.9 we have enough [breaking changes](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:
http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/

this is jquery.migrate.js which is used for migrations.